# MISMATCH GA4 / GOOGLE ADS

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

During the phase of tracking we recognised a mismatch related to some data between GA4 and Google ADS. To be more clear the problem is related to the number of conversions recorded in GA4 and Google ADS because for the same event we have two different values and it's clearly wrong. Can someone help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Ads only reports on conversions it was involved in, and it reports them on the date the user clicked on the ad and not the date the conversion happened.

Google Analytics attributes conversions on a last-click basis. So even if Google Ads was involved in a conversion, it might attribute it to a different source that was involved later.